# Ignoring HTML tags to highlight matching words

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I want to replace HTML template content with new one after highlighting the words those match the search input.

As shown in the snippet, I am using a highlight filter that adds yellow background to matched words by adding `&zwj;<span class="highlighted">$1&zwj;</span>`.

**Question one**

The problem is that sometimes highlighting doesn't execute and I can't figure out why, for example, when searching for `accountin`, then it is highlighted, but when searching for `accounting`, then it's not highlighted.

This problem occurs only when the matched word is inside some sub-tags such as `<bold>` and `<tag>` and others, you can try to search for `accounting` and you'll see what I mean. Why does this happen? and how to fix it?

**Question two**

In the HTML, I am using material icons such as `<md-icon class="material-icons ltr">folder</md-icon>` , and when searching for `folder`, then the the highlighting will occur on this icon.

Even if I use icons as svg like `<md-icon md-svg-src="path/user.svg"></md-icon>` , the same problem will happen.

So, is there any way to avoid this?

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["ngMaterial"])
.filter('highlight', function ($sce) {
        function mapText(text,tag,tagvalue){
            var reg = new RegExp("[\>][^\<\>.]*"+tag+"[^\<\>.][\<]*","gi");
            var result = text.replace(reg,function(item,exp){               
                var subRegex = new RegExp(tag,"gi");
                return item.replace(subRegex,tagvalue);
            });
            return result;
        }
        return function (text, searchSrting) {
            if(searchSrting){
                searchSrting = searchSrting.split(/\s+/);
                if(typeof text !== "undefined") {
                        for (var i = 0; i < searchSrting.length; i++) {
                            if(searchSrting[i]==""){
                                continue;
                            }
                            else{
                                var tagvalue = '&zwj;<span class="highlighted">' + searchSrting[i] + '&zwj;</span>';
                                text = mapText(text, searchSrting[i], tagvalue);
                            }
                        }
                }
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
            }
        }
    })
.controller("main", function($scope){ 
  $scope.searchString="";
  $scope.content="<module> <ti-tle>User Management</ti-tle><br><tag-group><tag>User Management</tag></tag-group><info-group><info><md-icon class='material-icons ltr'>perm_identity</md-icon>published by: Ha ba</info>        <info><md-icon class='material-icons ltr'>folder</md-icon>User Management</info><info><md-icon class='material-icons ltr'>publish</md-icon>published: 25 May 2016</info></info-group><hr>In <bold>AMe</bold>, you can manage multiple bank accounts <br><br>    <sub-title>        Introduction  Accounting</sub-title>    The Sales Planner is a useful step-by-step guide created to help you implement your sales funnel    <br>Accounting    Go to <bold>Accounting</bold> ‣ <bold>Configuration</bold> ‣ <bold>Bank Accounts</bold> and click on the Bank item. Edit it        <note><md-icon class='material-icons'>error_outline</md-icon>         will detect the bank account type (e.g. IBAN) to allow some payment method like SEPA.    </note>    <br><br>    <sub-title>        Set up your first sales team    </sub-title>    For example, if within your company Tim is selling products and John is selling maintenance contracts, they will be assigned to different teams and will only receive opportunities that make sense to them.    <br><br>        <sub-title>        Set up incoming email to generate opportunities    </sub-title>    In CRM, one way to generate opportunities into your sales team is to create a generic email address as a trigger.    </module>";
})
```

```css
module{
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #484848;
    }
    ti-tle {
        font-size: x-large;
        color: rgb(50, 118, 177);
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    tag-group{
        display: block;
        line-height: 3;
    }
    tag{
        background-color: #daebe8;
        padding:2px 6px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 2px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #667292;
    }
    tag:hover{
        background-color: #87bdd8;
    }
    info-group{display: block}
    info{
        color: gray;
        margin: 4px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    sub-title{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        display: block;
        line-height: 2;
    }
    img{
        display: block;
        margin: 30px 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    bold{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    note{
        background-color: antiquewhite;
    }
    .highlighted {
        background: yellow;
    }
    md-icon{direction: ltr}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="main">
  <label>search</label>
  <input ng-model="searchString"/>
  <div ng-if="!searchString">
<module>
    <ti-tle>User Management</ti-tle>
    <br>
    <tag-group>
        <tag>User Management</tag>
    </tag-group>
    <info-group>
        <info><md-icon class="material-icons ltr">perm_identity</md-icon>published by: Ha ba</info>
        <info><md-icon class="material-icons ltr">folder</md-icon>User Management</info>
        <info><md-icon class="material-icons ltr">publish</md-icon>published: 25 May 2016</info>
    </info-group>
    <hr>

    In <bold>AMe</bold>, you can manage multiple bank accounts
    <br><br>
    <sub-title>
        Introduction Accounting
    </sub-title>
    The Sales Planner is a useful step-by-step guide created to help you implement your sales funnel
    <br>
  Accounting
    Go to <bold>
  Accounting</bold> ‣ <bold>Configuration</bold> ‣ <bold>Bank Accounts</bold> and click on the Bank item. Edit it
    <note><md-icon class="material-icons">error_outline</md-icon>
       will detect the bank account type (e.g. IBAN) to allow some payment method like SEPA.
    </note>
    <br><br>
    <sub-title>
        Set up your first sales team
    </sub-title>
    For example, if within your company Tim is selling products and John is selling maintenance contracts, they will be assigned to different teams and will only receive opportunities that make sense to them.


    <br><br>
    <sub-title>
        Set up incoming email to generate opportunities
    </sub-title>
    In  CRM, one way to generate opportunities into your sales team is to create a generic email address as a trigger. For example, if
</module>

  
  </div>
  <div ng-if="searchString"  ng-bind-html="content | highlight:searchString"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried using [mark.js](https://markjs.io)?

Comment: Actually, there is no documentation about using mark.js in angularjs. @dude

Comment: Sure, you'll have to implement the filter yourself. But this would make it 10x faster and easier and would solve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I am sorry for quick tested answer.

Here is your answers:

```
var reg = new RegExp("[\>][^\<\>.]*"+tag+"[^\<\>.][\<]*","gi");
```

in this line regex searchs for any character but not '><'. this is whay your code is working wrong correct one is here:

```
var reg = new RegExp("[\>][^\<\>.]*"+tag+"[^\<\>.]*[\<]*","gi");
```

Part 2: in this code you are replacing words one by one. so when you replaced one word is second includes that word regex will not match. Example:

Our highlight words are fire and fireman.

```
var text = "<div>fireman has killed fire</div>";
```

after first loop text will be like:

```
text = "<div><highlight>fire</highlight>man has killed <highlight>fire</highlight></div>";
```

so our regex won't match second word in this new text.

but if we sort our array by text length. this problem will be solved.

in `<md-icon class="material-icons ltr">folder</md-icon>` case looks like this regex won't help you. if you want to do this with regex on your project you can add all of cases in your regex.

But spesific usages in regex like this... I don't think that's the best way to do that.

Because; in the future if you decide to change your icon library. you will have to change your regex too. And regex is not first look understandable lanugage. In the end this will be a very very bad hidden bussiness.

I hope you can find what you're looking for.